# GeoServer: WMS does not show feature after geometry update

Tags: geoserver, wms

In my application, I let the user update the **geometry** of a feature via **WFS-T**. After restfully saving the feature to the database, the **feature is gone in WMS images**, it just disappears. When I request the Layer via WFS, the updated feature is still there with it's new geometries, it just does not get rendered on WMS requests.

EDIT: The exported features look the same, except for the slightly changed geometry. They both can be shown on a map without problems as GML or GeoJSON.

Here is the feature as GML export before the geometry edit:

```
<gml:featureMember>
<ws:layername fid="layername.1">
<gml:boundedBy>
<gml:Box srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
<gml:coordinates xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">6.784233,51.44859 6.92345,51.496109</gml:coordinates>
</gml:Box>
</gml:boundedBy>
<ws:the_geom>
<gml:MultiPolygon srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
<gml:polygonMember>
<gml:Polygon>
<gml:outerBoundaryIs>
<gml:LinearRing>
<gml:coordinates xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">
6.91873,51.46989 6.91551,51.46743 6.913883,51.466128 6.9129,51.46699 6.910999,51.46771 6.909944,51.468109 6.9087,51.46858 6.91007,51.47018 6.909879,51.470428 6.912149,51.472895 6.912696,51.472927 6.913296,51.472638 6.91374,51.47314 6.91237,51.47311 6.9098,51.47339 6.90863,51.47349 6.90607,51.47384 6.90482,51.47395 6.90321,51.47356 6.90224,51.47345 6.90143,51.47373 6.9005,51.47421 6.89993,51.47434 6.89925,51.47432 6.89675,51.47386 6.89615,51.47393 6.89508,51.47442 6.89506,51.474897 6.89415,51.47627 6.89453,51.47817 6.895009,51.478904 6.894312,51.479189 6.893815,51.479068 6.892794,51.479504 6.891765,51.478901 6.889965,51.479098 6.888861,51.477185 6.88861,51.476324 6.888053,51.475937 6.886914,51.476347 6.886606,51.47611 6.885697,51.476208 6.885369,51.475204 6.886542,51.474159 6.886554,51.474009 6.886012,51.472582 6.885084,51.473139 6.88448,51.473458 6.883971,51.473801 6.880841,51.473947 6.880712,51.474107 6.880355,51.474122 6.879982,51.473653 6.879249,51.470983 6.877363,51.471217 6.874095,51.470246 6.8737,51.47061 6.872148,51.472283 6.87192,51.47253 6.86997,51.47176 6.86833,51.47044 6.86803,51.46964 6.867937,51.46922 6.870826,51.468187 6.87157,51.46758 6.872446,51.467467 6.875913,51.466399 6.876334,51.466055 6.87634,51.46605 6.876208,51.465704 6.876053,51.465785 6.871417,51.467596 6.870833,51.467011 6.86737,51.466435 6.867262,51.466203 6.867778,51.466036 6.867635,51.46511 6.86683,51.46515 6.86401,51.46469 6.86324,51.46324 6.863201,51.463007 6.862684,51.463024 6.862214,51.463666 6.857387,51.463078 6.857372,51.462228 6.85524,51.46218 6.852644,51.46227 6.85174,51.462072 6.851062,51.46012 6.850004,51.46034 6.849667,51.46174 6.846858,51.462415 6.846405,51.462452 6.84523,51.46244 6.845047,51.462489 6.84506,51.46244 6.84388,51.460059 6.84507,51.45982 6.845263,51.459719 6.84516,51.45894 6.845156,51.458935 6.844883,51.459477 6.843134,51.460014 6.841853,51.460102 6.839799,51.45592 6.840572,51.45342 6.840416,51.453134 6.8434,51.4521 6.84327,51.45189 6.84287,51.4505 6.84076,51.45094 6.83821,51.45168 6.8361,51.45203 6.833731,51.452015 6.833607,51.453139 6.83482,51.45505 6.831529,51.456362 6.8244,51.45322 6.82374,51.45391 6.82064,51.45599 6.81594,51.45731 6.81102,51.45637 6.80996,51.45555 6.808838,51.453728 6.807948,51.452507 6.806629,51.450466 6.805199,51.449539 6.801349,51.44859 6.79777,51.448757 6.79404,51.449089 6.789251,51.449768 6.786442,51.449887 6.784472,51.449939 6.784233,51.450386 6.785515,51.45037 6.790258,51.455545 6.791829,51.45633 6.795339,51.458263 6.797085,51.459276 6.797974,51.460195 6.798659,51.461341 6.800209,51.464304 6.8027,51.46384 6.80336,51.46586 6.80415,51.46739 6.803416,51.467443 6.80368,51.46817 6.80383,51.46846 6.80382,51.46909 6.8074,51.47054 6.8103,51.4718 6.81268,51.47284 6.812841,51.472783 6.81341,51.47258 6.81446,51.47215 6.81505,51.4719 6.81521,51.47184 6.81573,51.47153 6.81601,51.47157 6.81637,51.47161 6.81669,51.47162 6.826743,51.474462 6.825674,51.476525 6.825836,51.477281 6.825104,51.481325 6.821604,51.481008 6.820925,51.480601 6.819245,51.480936 6.81301,51.47759 6.81267,51.47786 6.81238,51.47822 6.81363,51.47892 6.8132,51.48034 6.81316,51.48073 6.81152,51.48214 6.81009,51.4842 6.81304,51.4849 6.81354,51.48506 6.81387,51.48493 6.814643,51.485239 6.81622,51.48587 6.81639,51.4865 6.81649,51.48685 6.81654,51.48708 6.821196,51.486324 6.825943,51.485984 6.826159,51.485204 6.826549,51.484684 6.826595,51.484634 6.827092,51.484793 6.829671,51.485634 6.831035,51.486084 6.838984,51.488155 6.850542,51.491074 6.854491,51.492344 6.859111,51.493232 6.859241,51.493255 6.86124,51.493632 6.86234,51.495353 6.862801,51.496109 6.865853,51.495967 6.865972,51.495818 6.86238,51.493762 6.866399,51.494311 6.872579,51.494952 6.873367,51.494962 6.878188,51.495025 6.883937,51.494853 6.889056,51.494735 6.888746,51.494002 6.887726,51.492695 6.886836,51.491474 6.890386,51.490345 6.894985,51.489014 6.898905,51.488133 6.90188,51.4885 6.904957,51.488785 6.905683,51.488852 6.90626,51.488906 6.9094,51.48653 6.909441,51.486402 6.90951,51.48619 6.910504,51.485518 6.911236,51.483552 6.911193,51.48347 6.911668,51.483222 6.912995,51.483496 6.913357,51.483333 6.913062,51.482494 6.913951,51.482044 6.914821,51.48161 6.914952,51.481324 6.914472,51.480985 6.916733,51.480094 6.917792,51.479684 6.917242,51.478784 6.917662,51.478486 6.917841,51.477875 6.918242,51.476525 6.918362,51.475268 6.917712,51.474336 6.917349,51.473971 6.919012,51.473856 6.920624,51.474323 6.922016,51.473631 6.923174,51.472907 6.92345,51.47286 6.92329,51.47277 6.92189,51.47094 6.92059,51.4708 6.91987,51.47036 6.91873,51.46989
</gml:coordinates>
</gml:LinearRing>
</gml:outerBoundaryIs>
</gml:Polygon>
</gml:polygonMember>
</gml:MultiPolygon>
</ws:the_geom>
<ws:myId>F223</ws:myId>
</ws:layername>
</gml:featureMember>
```

After the geometry update:

```
<gml:featureMember>
<ws:layername fid="layername.1">
<gml:boundedBy>
<gml:Box srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
<gml:coordinates xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">6.784233,51.44853 6.92345,51.496109</gml:coordinates>
</gml:Box>
</gml:boundedBy>
<ws:the_geom>
<gml:MultiPolygon srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
<gml:polygonMember>
<gml:Polygon>
<gml:outerBoundaryIs>
<gml:LinearRing>
<gml:coordinates xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">
6.91873,51.46989 6.91551,51.46743 6.913883,51.466128 6.9129,51.46699 6.910999,51.46771 6.909944,51.468109 6.9087,51.46858 6.91007,51.47018 6.909879,51.470428 6.912149,51.472895 6.912696,51.472927 6.913296,51.472638 6.91374,51.47314 6.91237,51.47311 6.9098,51.47339 6.90863,51.47349 6.90607,51.47384 6.90482,51.47395 6.90321,51.47356 6.90224,51.47345 6.90143,51.47373 6.9005,51.47421 6.89993,51.47434 6.89925,51.47432 6.89675,51.47386 6.89964,51.47136 6.89837,51.47068 6.8973,51.47004 6.89684,51.46975 6.89422,51.46886 6.893885,51.468617 6.893332,51.468449 6.892237,51.468116 6.890702,51.467719 6.88978,51.46748 6.88818,51.46702 6.886214,51.466113 6.885692,51.465872 6.88142,51.4639 6.88105,51.46364 6.88097,51.46358 6.87953,51.46243 6.87928,51.462291 6.87442,51.4596 6.87332,51.45902 6.87109,51.45767 6.86904,51.45764 6.86582,51.45825 6.86596,51.45859 6.86599,51.45874 6.86334,51.45869 6.86229,51.45844 6.86147,51.4585 6.8607,51.458 6.8583,51.45806 6.85669,51.4581 6.854612,51.458022 6.853965,51.457998 6.85298,51.458113 6.851213,51.458064 6.850977,51.458068 6.84891,51.4581 6.848196,51.458246 6.846359,51.458243 6.84598,51.45852 6.84517,51.45649 6.84482,51.45548 6.84448,51.45421 6.844236,51.454165 6.84352,51.45248 6.8434,51.4521 6.84327,51.45189 6.84287,51.4505 6.841593,51.450349 6.84017,51.45018 6.83708,51.44962 6.83378,51.44924 6.82821,51.44853 6.82732,51.44893 6.82726,51.44911 6.82695,51.44969 6.82654,51.4504 6.8244,51.45322 6.82374,51.45391 6.82064,51.45599 6.81594,51.45731 6.81102,51.45637 6.80996,51.45555 6.808838,51.453728 6.807948,51.452507 6.806629,51.450466 6.805199,51.449539 6.801349,51.44859 6.79777,51.448757 6.79404,51.449089 6.789251,51.449768 6.786442,51.449887 6.784472,51.449939 6.784233,51.450386 6.785515,51.45037 6.790258,51.455545 6.791829,51.45633 6.795339,51.458263 6.797085,51.459276 6.797974,51.460195 6.798659,51.461341 6.800209,51.464304 6.8027,51.46384 6.80336,51.46586 6.80415,51.46739 6.803416,51.467443 6.80368,51.46817 6.80383,51.46846 6.80382,51.46909 6.8074,51.47054 6.8103,51.4718 6.81268,51.47284 6.81076,51.47365 6.8093,51.47425 6.80922,51.47441 6.80879,51.47453 6.808674,51.474647 6.80859,51.47473 6.80974,51.47554 6.81301,51.47759 6.81267,51.47786 6.81238,51.47822 6.81363,51.47892 6.8132,51.48034 6.81316,51.48073 6.81152,51.48214 6.81009,51.4842 6.81304,51.4849 6.81354,51.48506 6.81387,51.48493 6.814643,51.485239 6.81622,51.48587 6.81639,51.4865 6.81649,51.48685 6.81654,51.48708 6.821196,51.486324 6.825943,51.485984 6.826159,51.485204 6.826549,51.484684 6.826595,51.484634 6.827092,51.484793 6.829671,51.485634 6.831035,51.486084 6.83130097,51.4861533 6.831331,51.486163 6.838984,51.488155 6.850542,51.491074 6.854491,51.492344 6.859111,51.493232 6.859241,51.493255 6.86124,51.493632 6.86234,51.495353 6.862801,51.496109 6.865853,51.495967 6.865972,51.495818 6.86238,51.493762 6.866399,51.494311 6.872579,51.494952 6.873367,51.494962 6.878188,51.495025 6.883937,51.494853 6.889056,51.494735 6.888746,51.494002 6.887726,51.492695 6.886836,51.491474 6.890386,51.490345 6.894985,51.489014 6.898905,51.488133 6.90188,51.4885 6.904957,51.488785 6.905683,51.488852 6.90626,51.488906 6.9094,51.48653 6.909441,51.486402 6.90951,51.48619 6.910504,51.485518 6.911236,51.483552 6.911193,51.48347 6.911668,51.483222 6.912995,51.483496 6.913357,51.483333 6.913062,51.482494 6.913951,51.482044 6.914821,51.48161 6.914952,51.481324 6.914472,51.480985 6.916733,51.480094 6.917792,51.479684 6.917242,51.478784 6.917662,51.478486 6.917841,51.477875 6.918242,51.476525 6.918362,51.475268 6.917712,51.474336 6.917349,51.473971 6.919012,51.473856 6.920624,51.474323 6.922016,51.473631 6.923174,51.472907 6.92345,51.47286 6.92329,51.47277 6.92189,51.47094 6.92059,51.4708 6.91987,51.47036 6.91873,51.46989
</gml:coordinates>
</gml:LinearRing>
</gml:outerBoundaryIs>
</gml:Polygon>
</gml:polygonMember>
</gml:MultiPolygon>
</ws:the_geom>
<ws:myId>F223</ws:myId>
</ws:layername>
</gml:featureMember>
<gml:featureMember>
```

EDIT: I am using MSSQL as Datastore.

Comment: please edit your question to show us the geometry before and after it has been edited

Comment: This seems to be an issue with MSSQL-Datastores. It does not happen with layers from a SHP-Datastore.

Comment: Are your polygons clockwise? I think MsSQL requires them to be orientated